# Issue with Xml parsing Using Regex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, xml-parsing

here is my xml received via webservice..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Quotes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://swanandmokashi.com">
  <QuoteOfTheDay>Hit any user to continue.</QuoteOfTheDay>
  <Author>Fuzzel Fish Administration Page</Author>
</Quotes>
```

and im trying to parse it by this in my connectionDidFinishLoading: ...

```
{            
 webData_str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *pattern = @"<QuoteOfTheDay>(.*)</QuoteOfTheDay><Author>(.*)</Author>";
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive                                                                            error:nil];

__block NSString *QuoteString,*author= nil;

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:webData_str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [webData_str length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

   // not executing...

    if (0 < [match numberOfRanges]) {
        NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        QuoteString = [webData_str substringWithRange:range];


        NSRange range1 = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
        author = [webData_str substringWithRange:range1];        

    }
}];        

final=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n%@",QuoteString,author];
NSLog(@"Final--- %@",final);
}
```

what's wrong in this? , execution flow not going inside block..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to use an XML parser (e.g. `NSXMLParser`) instead of regular 
expressions.

But to answer your concrete problem: Your regex does not match the whitespace (newline and spaces) between `</QuoteOfTheDay>` and `<Author>`. If you change the pattern to

```
NSString *pattern = @"<QuoteOfTheDay>(.*)</QuoteOfTheDay>\\s*<Author>(.*)</Author>";
```

you will get the expected output.

Comment: perfect..thanks.. yes NSXMlParser would be better option but as number  of tags were only two i'd choose regex..